# Get shorter file URL from Google Cloud Storage (with Firebase Cloud Functions)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have the following Firebase Cloud Function to get the URL of the file stored in Google Cloud Storage.

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename: 'service-account.json'});

exports.generateFileLink = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  const object = event.data;
  const filePath = object.name;
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
  const file = bucket.file(filePath);
  const action = 'read';
  const expires = '03-09-2491';
  return file.getSignedUrl({action, expires}).then(signedUrls => {
    console.log(signedUrls[0])
  });
})
```

This returns the correct URL, but it is over 600 characters long. The URL for the same file as seen on the Firebase web console is less than 200 characters long. Is there any way I can retrieve the URL using firebase-admin or firebase-functions modules to get the shorter URL?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is that we're working on a `firebase-admin` Storage client, but it's still a little ways away. For now, signed URLs are the way to go if you need to create a download URL in a function.

Why do you need to generate signed URLs in the function vs using the download URLs provided by Firebase? Is it that you can't retrieve the URL via a client in the function and you need to move it somewhere else?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any methods to retrieve file's download URLs using any of the Firebase modules. I don't really need a signed URL, just a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/FIRStorageReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRStorageReference(im)downloadURLWithCompletion:) inside a cloud function.

Comment: Sorry, let me correct myself. I do want a signed URL. The Firebase download URL has a token attribute in it (about 36 characters), whereas the Google Cloud Storage has a Signature (200+ characters).  I am looking for a download URL with a smaller size

Comment: @SalilThakur unfortunately we don't yet support the Firebase download URLs through the standard GCS clients. As mentioned, we're working to solve this, but for now you'll have to use the long ones or store a `gs://` URI and have the clients get an actual download URL. Another option is to investigate a link shortener (like bit.ly) to expand out to the full signed URL

Comment: Thanks Mike! Will keep a watch for this feature in future updates.